# Cant mix milk and coffe in my cup

Tags: java, multithreading

Hm ok,

because of the Observer-Pattern is overweight in here, i try it by my own.

Somehow either the coffe or the milk is not put in the cup.

```
package test;
import java.util.*;
public class Task extends Thread {

    private static final Task EMPTY_TASK = null;

    private Task postTask = EMPTY_TASK;
    private final List<Task> preconditions;

    public Task() {
        super();
        preconditions = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public Task(final String name, final Task... preliminaries) {
        super(name);
        this.preconditions = new ArrayList<Task>(Arrays.asList(preliminaries));
        for (Task preliminary : preliminaries) {
            preliminary.setPostTask(this);
        }
    }

    private void setPostTask(final Task postTask) {
        this.postTask = postTask;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Working " + this);
        if (postTask != null) {
            postTask.informSolved(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (preconditions.size() == 0) {
            super.start();
        } else {
            System.out.println("The " + getName() + " cant start: " + preconditions
                    + " not yet solved.");
        }
    }

    private synchronized void informSolved(final Task task) {
        preconditions.remove(task);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Task cup = new Task("Cup");
        Task milk = new Task("Milk", cup);
        Task coffee = new Task("Coffee", cup);
        Task mix = new Task("Mix", milk, coffee);

        mix.start();
        milk.start();
        cup.start();
        coffee.start();
    }
}
```

This shows on the Console:

```
The Mix cant start: [Milk, Coffee] not yet solved.
The Milk cant start: [Cup] not yet solved.
The Coffee cant start: [Cup] not yet solved.
Working Cup
Working Coffee
The Mix cant start: [Milk] not yet solved.
```

My Question: What do i have to do to get my coffe mixed?

Comment: When I read your title I thought I was high.

Comment: in your code while a task could have many preliminaries each preliminary could have only one post task. but in your example "cup" should have 2 postTask -> milk and coffee. so change "setPostTask" with "addPostTask" logic and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is why you cant have your morning coffee:

```
private void setPostTask(final Task postTask) {
   this.postTask = postTask;
}
```

a task can only have a single post task, and in your case cup needs to have 2 - coffee and milk. make postTask into postTasks

Answer (score 1):

Note that the entire approach of extending `Thread`s is questionable. Here is an example of a more recommended programming style:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class CoffeeMixing
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new CoffeeMixing().mix();
  }
  private void mix()
  {
    ExecutorService e=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future<?> cup=e.submit(new Task("cup"));
    Future<?> milk=e.submit(new Task("Milk", cup));
    Future<?> coffee=e.submit(new Task("Coffee", cup));
    Future<?> mix=e.submit(new Task("Mix", milk, coffee));
    try
    {
      mix.get();
      System.out.println("Now I have my coffee");
    }
    catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex)
    {
      System.out.println("while trying to get coffee: "+ex);
    }
  }
  final class Task implements Callable<Void>
  {
    private final String name;
    private final List<Future<?>> preconditions;

    Task(String name)
    {
      this.name=name;
      preconditions=Collections.emptyList();
    }
    Task(String name, Future<?>... pre)
    {
      this.name=name;
      preconditions=Arrays.asList(pre);
    }
    public Void call() throws Exception
    {
      if(!preconditions.isEmpty())
      {
        System.out.println(name+" awaiting preconditions");
        for(Future<?> f: preconditions) f.get();
      }
      System.out.println("Working "+name);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is milk and coffee executed async? `void call` uses a loop inside.

Comment: All of them are executed asynchronous. [`Future.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) waits for the asynchronous completion. But if they complete fast enough, the `ExecutorService` will re-use the then-free `Thread` for the next `Task`.

Comment: To `wait` a few ms is a recommended programming style? Even a quantum-computer will need at least 3ms then instead of 1ms. If i take 3 times longer to make my coffee my collegues put me to madhouse.

Comment: @Peter Rader: what are you talking about? Who said anything about “a few ms”? `Future.get()` waits for the *completion* of the task, not waiting a single cycle if the task has been completed already. This approach is *far faster* than yours as in your code the threads *have not even been started* at the time the preconditions are fulfilled. Starting a thread takes significant time.

Comment: See, `get` calls `innerGet` calls `acquireSharedInterruptibly(0)` calls `doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(0)` calls `addWaiter` calls `tryAcquireShared` who calls wait and may throw a InterruptedException.

Comment: @Peter Rader: Don’t take it personally but the technique behind it seems to be way beyond your programming experience. Just belief that it has been developed by concurrency experts in order to create the most efficient solution. You are not the man to create a better solution, especially not by creating subclasses of `Thread`. By the way, `tryAcquireShared` is invoked *before* `doAcquireSharedInterruptibly` so it returns immediately if the task has been finished. But anyway, as already said, your code *starting* threads at the point of completion is *way slower*.

Comment: I hope i can be a concurrency expert one time, if the way to be that to be pissed some times: its ok! See, i made some tests and found `final class Task` in my coffee-case works faster.

Comment: As long as your operations are no-ops, even executing them in a single-threaded loop would be much faster. But in the end it’s more than just performance. Not using the concurrency tools introduced with Java 5 means creating potentially error-prone code, reinventing the wheel, etc. [Give it a try](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html).